# Narrowing a type on an interface provided by an external module

Tags: typescript

I have an external module (installed from `@types/some-module`). I want to extend an interface within a namespace of that module, so that one of the properties on that interface is *narrower* than what is given by the module.

[Here's a **Playground Link**](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEHsCcEsHNoHYEMA2A6AJmgLgZwFAYCmAxikpEaALbgYCuKVARLuNUQLS0NPOgBvfKFDIOuAA5ISVAMrsiAOSTipMwcJGhE2IpABm0uQoCSCXQaMatW6BgBcoXNhgJYAbk0iAvpt+-8EBoAT0wcAmIyCioeRhY2Dm46OP4hETEiSSt5DmVVKzTbcz1DdRyiMwtSqkKbO0dmfXBwfgAfUGYAIwpmd1AggHcACyRsUBNQAaRzUGxwUAxwL1BfH3xfIA)

```
// original.d.ts
namespace SomeNamespace {
  interface SomeInterface {
    id: string;
  }
}

// my.d.ts
declare module 'some-module' {
  namespace SomeNamespace {
    interface SomeInterface {
      id: 'foo' | 'bar'; // what I want to do
    }
  }
}
```

I predictably get an error

> ```
> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property
> 'id' must be of type 'string', but here has type '"foo" | "bar"'. ts(2717)
> ```

Is it possible? I tried adding `unknown` and even `any`, but it doesn't accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module augmentation allows you to add to an interface but not change existing member types. Your only option is to extend the interface and use type assertions to your derived interface where apropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately 'foo'|'bar' isn't a string type, the union type works more like an enum in typescript.

Best idea would be a factory method that restricts the id to 'foo'|'bar'.
Unfortunately I don't have ideas to help your autocomplete for these values.